# Spring & Keycloak - null principal

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, keycloak

I am trying to configure my `Spring Boot` application to use `Keycloak` as SSO.

I am following standard tutorials in this topic:

First add dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
                <version>13.0.1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Second, fill properties

```
# Keycloak
keycloak.realm                      = Mixeway
keycloak.auth-server-url            = http://localhost:8180/auth
keycloak.ssl-required               = external
keycloak.resource                   = MixewayApp
keycloak.credentials.secret         = secret
keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings = false
keycloak.bearer-only                = false
keycloak.security-constraints[0].authRoles[0]=USER
keycloak.security-constraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/v2/auth/keycloak
```

Third create controller to handle authentication

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/v2/auth/keycloak")
    public void authUsingKeycloak(Principal principal){
        log.info("user {} logged using keycloak", principal.getName());
    }
```

Authentication works properly. I can see logs:

```
2021-12-30 10:18:48.213 DEBUG 6947 --- [nio-8443-exec-3] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   : Verifying tokens
2021-12-30 10:18:48.265 DEBUG 6947 --- [nio-8443-exec-3] o.k.a.rotation.JWKPublicKeyLocator       : Realm public keys successfully retrieved for client MixewayApp. New kids: [mpkD1RwCaaIbp8tN-a9__hlc03UpxrQ8SE5atlDrF78]
2021-12-30 10:18:48.270 DEBUG 6947 --- [nio-8443-exec-3] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   : Token Verification succeeded!
2021-12-30 10:18:48.277 DEBUG 6947 --- [nio-8443-exec-3] o.k.a.rotation.JWKPublicKeyLocator       : Realm public keys successfully retrieved for client MixewayApp. New kids: [mpkD1RwCaaIbp8tN-a9__hlc03UpxrQ8SE5atlDrF78]
2021-12-30 10:18:48.277 DEBUG 6947 --- [nio-8443-exec-3] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   : successful authenticated
2021-12-30 10:18:48.283 DEBUG 6947 --- [nio-8443-exec-3] o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator        : User '343050ef-bc48-48ae-af93-5dd3f0830956' invoking 'https://localhost:8443/v2/auth/keycloak?state=d1ebaf04-c0fd-4415-8f70-56b68e9f8485&session_state=e2e280a0-428d-4481-99c6-f45cfa171f4c&code=da46d2ee-14b5-45ef-a15f-6a69e196f092.e2e280a0-428d-4481-99c6-f45cfa171f4c.0b00edfd-1474-42ec-a2df-f2754b830dc6' on client 'MixewayApp'
2021-12-30 10:18:48.283 DEBUG 6947 --- [nio-8443-exec-3] o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator        : AUTHENTICATED
2021-12-30 10:18:48.291 DEBUG 6947 --- [nio-8443-exec-4] o.k.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler       : adminRequest https://localhost:8443/v2/auth/keycloak
2021-12-30 10:18:48.291 DEBUG 6947 --- [nio-8443-exec-4] o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator        : AUTHENTICATED: was cached
2021-12-30 10:18:48.291 DEBUG 6947 --- [nio-8443-exec-4] .k.a.t.AbstractAuthenticatedActionsValve : AuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke /v2/auth/keycloak
```

However I am getting `NullPointer` Exception due to null `Principal` object. Can anyone give me a hint how to configure keycloak auth in spring so that principal object is set properly?

**EDIT**

after rewriting controller to

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/v2/auth/keycloak")
    public void authUsingKeycloakGet(HttpServletRequest request){
        KeycloakPrincipal principal=(KeycloakPrincipal) request.getUserPrincipal();
        KeycloakSecurityContext session = principal.getKeycloakSecurityContext();
        AccessToken accessToken = session.getToken();
    }
```

and debugging application I am able to see principal in `HttpServletRequest` but both principal and `request.getUserPrincipal()` is still null:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As it is in controller level and you are creating an endPoint, you need to use @RequestBody annotation for the body inputs, @RequestParam annotation for request parameters (i.e. yourEndPoint?id=1) or @PathVariable for path variables in the endPoint (i.e. yourEndPoint/1).

Comment: I am afraid this is not the case. I have edited question adding more debug